Error when trying to build an android bundle 'File 'root/lib/arm64-v8a/include/cvkernels.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.'
Error when trying to build an android bundle when applying javacv dependencies in android studio.

  implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.4.4'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:4.0.1-1.4.4:android-arm64'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:4.0.1-1.4.4:android-arm'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:4.0.1-1.4.4:android-x86


Error:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebugBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
   > File 'root/lib/arm64-v8a/include/cvkernels.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.

Problem solving so that the application can be built with budle

Please try again with the newest version of JavaCV.
